# List of a list of a list

Tags: r

This screenshot shows my data. I have a list of a list of a list and I have to calculate for each list as an example <<  ou1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvcK4.png)]$`1`$Growth  >> the mean for Growth....

I have tried several things, but nothing really works. This code is the closest to what I am trying to achieve, unfortunately it doesn't work either. With the second code I just calculate the mean for each element, what doesn't make sense. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could address the problem? How can I use lapply on list of a list of a list?

```
lapply(ou1, sapply, mean)

lapply(ou1[[1]]$`1`$Growth, sapply, mean)
```

The attached image shows a section of my dataset.

[image]

Comment: The package `purrr` should be helpful. In particular `map_depth()` may help you dig down into a nested list a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work on your data.

```
result <- sapply(unlist(ou1, recursive = FALSE), function(x) 
                 mean(x$Growth, na.rm = TRUE))
```

`unlist` with `recurisive = FALSE` should bring the list all at one level. You can iterate over them using `sapply` and get the average of `Growth` column from each dataframe. `result` should have a vector of numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

with toy data, this works;

```
a <- list(list(iris),list(iris),list(iris))

lapply(a,FUN = function(x) mean(x[[1]]$Sepal.Width))
```

**output;**

```
3.05733333333333
3.05733333333333
3.05733333333333
```

---

so in your case, it should be;

```
lapply(ou1,FUN = function(x) mean(x$`1`$Growth))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :-) ! But I have a lot of other lists as u can see in the picture, how can I do it for list[[1]]$`2` until 15 and for the next list without always chaning the number by hand? Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`

```
library(purrr)
map_dbl(a, ~ mean(.x[[1]]$Sepal.Width))
[1] 3.057333 3.057333 3.057333
```